# "closest()" is not working in else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made simple functionality for select(add check) div on 1st click and 2nd click it will be remove, I have used "closest()" in else condition. Not getting.

Please help.

For code [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/rupesx26/16dsa65j/8/)

JS:=

```
var selected = $('.demo-select');
selected.click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    if ($('.demo-select').hasClass('selected')) {
        //alert(1);
        $(this).append('<p class="test">check</p>');
    } else {
        //alert(2);
        $('.demo-select').closest('.test').remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Need to use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) as you are looking for a descendant element not an ancestor element([.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) is used to find an ancestor element matching the passed selector).

```
$(this).find('.test').remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8gjz6yzr/)

Answer (score 4):

Here you need to use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [closet()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

find() : Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element

closet() : For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```js
var selected = $('.demo-select');
selected.click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  if ($('.demo-select').hasClass('selected')) {
    //alert(1);
    $(this).append('<p class="test">check</p>');
  } else {
    //alert(2);
    $(this).closest('.test').remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.demo-select {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.test {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo-select"></div>
<div class="demo-select"></div>
<div class="demo-select"></div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tharindukumara/3b4forzd/

Answer (score 3):

Use `find()` to achieve this. As `closest()` will traverse up through its ancestors in the DOM tree and not its decendents.

```
$('.demo-select').find('.test').remove(); //OR simply $(this).find('.test').remove()
```

**Update**

For multiple elements use `$(this)`

```
var selected = $('.demo-select');
selected.click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) { //HERE $(this)
        //alert(1);
        $(this).append('<p class="test">check</p>');
    } else {
        //alert(2);
        $('this').find('.test').remove(); //HERE $(this) and find()
    }
});
```

Comment: @Rupesh for multiple elements use `$(this)` Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/16dsa65j/11/).

Answer (score 2):

`closest` will get you the closest ancestor. You should use `find` to get the `.test`:

```
var selected = $('.demo-select');
selected.click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

    if ($('.demo-select').hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).append('<p class="test">check</p>')
    } else {
        $(this).find('.test').remove();
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/16dsa65j/4/

`find`:

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/find/

**EDIT**

For multiple elements:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/16dsa65j/9/

Comment: Hey thanks for your time but I have just updated http://jsfiddle.net/rupesx26/16dsa65j/8/ but if "demo-select" is more than one and then "find () " may not work because it will remove all check

Comment: @Rupesh http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/16dsa65j/9/ Check updated fiddle, Used `$(this)` inside `click` handler and `find`

Answer (score 0):

you need to [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the element instead of doing closest selection for the element.

```
$('.demo-select').find('.test').remove();
```

Comment: not working for more then one "demo select" http://jsfiddle.net/rupesx26/16dsa65j/10/ please check

Comment: add this $(this).find('.test').remove();